# jquery. Need a slider, carousel, galleri for DIV's that does not use ID's (multible on one page)

Tags: jquery, slider, gallery

I am looking for something like CODA slider (http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html), but need two on each page. And since the example works with an ID, then I cannot use it.

Is there another slider/gallery for DIVs with all sorts of content that can be used without having to use an ID?

BR. Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to do the trick:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/